# Carousel not working if the code is added dynamically by jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, carousel

I've a carousel on my website, that works perfectly on hardcoding it. This is what the code looks like:

```
<div class="w-full flex justify-center">
   <div class="gallery js-flickity"
       data-flickity-options='{ "wrapAround": true }'
   >
     <div class="gallery-cell">
       <div class="w-full flex justify-center">
           <img src="./img/sidenav-1/clients-01.png" class="client-image"/>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="gallery-cell">
       <div class="w-full flex justify-center">
          <img src="./img/sidenav-1/clients-02.jpeg" class="client-image" />
       </div>
     </div>                  
 </div>
```

I've to use this carousel due to certain coding restricions I've so I can't change it. Now I have to connect this webpage to an admin panel, in which I'm using PHP for fetching the values from the database and echoing the same entire code and usind jQuery to put it in place. But If I do so instead of a carousel the images are displayed one beneath the other.

jQuery Code:

```
<script>
  $.ajax({url: "API/clients.php", success: function(result){
     $("#append_clients").html(result);
  }});
</script>
```

PHP:

```
$resultee = '<div class="gallery js-flickity" data-flickity-options=\'{ "wrapAround": true }\'>';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Clients;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$conn->close();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $image_path = $row["image_address"];
      $client_name = $row["client_name"];
      $client_desc = $row["client_desc"];
    $resultee .= '<div class="gallery-cell"><div class="w-full flex justify-center"><img src="'.$image_path.'" class="client-image" /></div></div>';
  }
} 

$resultee .= '</div>';
```

CSS and JS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flickity/1.0.0/flickity.css" />
<style>
.gallery {
  width: 93vw;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  margin-left: -5%;
}

.gallery-cell {
  width: 93vw;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
    
   
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flickity/1.0.0/flickity.pkgd.js"><script>
```

Can anyone please help, I'm unsure what to do

Comment: can you provide a dummy data instead of php, it'll be really helpful

Comment: It is possible that the carousel script executes before the asynchronous query data is returned. Maybe you need to call carousel initiation after ajax is loaded and generated new html code.

Comment: @Robert How can I do that, can you suggest me a course of action to try? Tried adding "async" to both the script tags, that didn't work

Comment: initialize the carousel after the data binding

Comment: How are you linking in your CSS and the carousel library? Could you show us your actual document?

Comment: I would try to add after `$("#append_clients").html(result);` such code `$('.js-flickity').flickity();`. I don't know if it will work, because I don't know this js library. It was just a quick look in documentation here: https://flickity.metafizzy.co/api.html

Comment: Eventually You can try to load flickity.js after You load html content (not before). I suppose it will trigger itselt after load and detect your carousel in html.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a dynamically loaded flickity carousel where all of my cells were initially stacked on top of each other. It could be two things: you're just adding elements to the html instead of using flickity 'append' to add items to the initialized carousel. Second, if you call 'resize' after on a visible and populated carousel, it should be able to measure and position the elements correctly.

```
/* init carousel via jquery */
var $carousel = $('.gallery').flickity( { "wrapAround": true } );

/* add item(s) to $carousel */
$carousel.flickity( 'append', your_item);

/* force a redraw */
$carousel.flickity('resize');
```

API for reference:
https://www.tszshan.org/home/new/common/js/flickity-docs/api.html#resize